# SMTP Email Settings for Gmail .NET Core Doesn't Work

Tags: .net-core, smtp, gmail

```
 "EmailSettings": {
    "PrimaryDomain": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "PrimaryPort": "587",
    "SecondayDomain": "smtp.live.com",
    "SecondaryPort": "587",
    "UsernameEmail": "example@gmail.com",
    "UsernamePassword": "mypassword",
    "FromEmail": "info",
    "ToEmail": "",
    "CcEmail": ""
  },
```

I wanted to send automail from via my mail. Appsettings.json in .NET Core I use this gmail settings for send but it doesn't work. I coulnd't send mail. Is this true or there is any mistake that U=I missed?

Comment: First of all check the server port (587) open or not
Second if Port is opened check the code its correct or not and what the error message comes if related to connection or something else

Answer (score 0):

Apart from these settings you have to configure your Gmail account.

1. Open your Gmail id.
2. Go to
   my account > sign-in & security > allow less
   secureApp:ON
3. Restart your server.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work for me. I want to be sure. The gmail settings are ture right ?